# Minecraft animations with commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do you do basic animations with commands please help. I tried using these ~ but there to complicated and Youtube doesn't help.

Comment: What are you trying to animate?

Answer (score 2):

You can but you must use command blocks.

Watch this useful video: